# In salesforce phptoolkit how to get dynamic dropdown values

Tags: php, soap, salesforce

- I want to know how can i retrieve values for a dropdown that's dynamic based on other field. For example : How do i get values for "Sub Category" if its dependent on "Category" dropdown.
- Also wanted to know how can i find all fields for "Case" which are required in order to submit new "Case". I am trying to do this using phptoolkit but i found no good documentation on it.

Comment: @mmix : Thanks for letting me know, i never knew you have to accept final answer. I thought the one had more votes was final answer and i always tried to vote but couldn't as i was newbie.

Comment: You can always accept answer on your question even when newbie. You need 20 rep to upvote which I believe you have now. Glad to see you here, hope you stay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP toolkit in essence is a WSDL SOAP wrapper so anything applicable to salesforce API web servce applies to PHP toolkit.

The following is a procedure to solve your problems (I dont have a PHP sample):

1. call `describeSObject` to retrieve information about the object
2. Each field in `describesObjectResult.Fields` has three important properties for you, `creatable`, `nillable` and `defaultedOnCreate`. If createable and not nillable and not defaulted you must provide a value, this answers question #2
3. if field type is picklist or multipcklist then fields' `picklistValues` contains a list of `PicklistEntry` elements. If picklist is dependent each entry contains a base64 encoded bitmap in `validFor` property. Each bit at position i is 0 or 1, corresponding to whether picklist entry is applicable for master picklist entry at position i.
4. You have to decode the bitmap and use it to determine for which master picklist entries this particular entry can be used. Unfortuantely for now its the only way.

I can give you a sample in javascript of how I did it (`lstCategories` and `lstSubcategories` are arrays of `PickListEntry`), `lstApplicableSubs` is created having the list of subcategories for every category. This should give you an approach to decoding:

```
    var b64 = new sforce.Base64Binary("");
    lstApplicableSubs = new Array(lstCategories.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < lstApplicableSubs.length; i++) lstApplicableSubs[i] = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < lstSubCategories.length; i++)
    {
        var map = b64.decode(lstSubCategories[i].validFor);
        for (var j = 0; j < lstCategories.length; j++)
        {
            var bits = map.charCodeAt(j >> 3);
            if ((bits & (0x80 >> (j & 0x07))) != 0) lstApplicableSubs[j].push(lstSubCategories[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: My another question is if field required if creatable, nillable and defaultedOnCreate all are set to "1" or any of them is set to "1"?

Comment: creatable means you can specify the value for it in INSERT DML, if 0 you cannot specify it at all (for example, formula field). nillable means the field value can be NULL (which means that you dont need to provide a value, it will default to null if missing). defaulted means that the field has a defined default value which will be set if you dont specify it. So you are looking 1,0,0 combination of the three, thats where you MUST provide a value or insert will break.

Comment: required = creatable == 1 and nillable == 0 and defauled == 0

Comment: They do not provide any proper documentation on how to use phptoolkit they provide. I am not googling to look for how to user their base64binary in phptoolkit. Normal base64 decode doesnt work.

Comment: @mmix have u ever implimented that code in PHP instead of Javascript?

Comment: Nope, but validFor should be decodable with any Base64 decoder, there is nothing special about salesfore base64. Keep in mind that the result of `base64_decode` is a binary value